# MYSQL Updating database using maths?

Tags: php, mysql

**My query:**

```
UPDATE `settings_products` SET `stock_osrs` = SUM(stock_osrs - 50)
```

I have a stock system in my admin panel which currently displays stock levels set by the admins, but I am creating an API so every payment that has been completed will take away the stock.

Lets say that the ordered amount is "50" like in the query and I want to take this away from the stock_osrs.

How exactly would I go about doing this?

EDIT: I am aware that I could use PHP to do the calculations and then update the table from that, but I feel this will be less reliable as I would have to do "50,000" - 50 = "45,950" and post that number to the database.

In this time there could have been another order which would cause the code to mess up, hence that I need to use SQL to achieve this!

Comment: Do not need the sum bit

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE `settings_products` SET `stock_osrs` = `stock_osrs` - 50
```

SUM() operates on groups of records - e.g., `SELECT SUM(stock_osrs) FROM settings_products WHERE...` would give you the total of stock_osrs for a group of records. It is possible to use SUM() as well - e.g., to get the SUM() of records in one table and store it in a field in another table, but that gets a bit more complicated. For simple inside-one-record math, just include the equation. You can even include multiple fields - e.g., `UPDATE inventory SET available = onhand - onorder` or similar statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just trying to do minus 50 on a field so this should work.

```
UPDATE `settings_products` SET `stock_osrs` = `stock_osrs` - 50
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query this might solve your problem .

you can simply execute mathematical operation directly.

```
UPDATE settings_product SET stock_osrs=stock_osrs-50;
```

i have verified the above query it worked ,try it

Answer (score -1):

I think you want something like this:

```
UPDATE 
  settings_products AS lg 
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      l.`stock_osrs` AS stock_osrs,
      COUNT(l.id) AS total,
      SUM(l.stock_osrs) AS SUM
    FROM
      stock_osrs l 
    GROUP BY l.`stock_osrs`) sub 
    ON lg.`stock_osrs` = sub.stock_osrs SET lg.stock_osrs = sub.sum - 50 ;
```

I am assuming that primary key of this table is `id`. May be you can modify it a little bit but this is the sort of thing you are looking for...